# How to delete records from two different tables that are linked with FK? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, sql-delete

I have two tables City and Buildings in my database. They are linked with `city_number` that is `Primary Key` in City table and `Foreign Key` in Buildings table. If user wants to delete record from City table I want to remove any records from the Buildings table that is tied to that City. I use unique auto incremented id passed through the argument to remove these records. My SQL Query looks like this:

```
DELETE C.*, B.*
FROM City AS C
    INNER JOIN Buildings AS B
        ON C.c_number = B.b_district
WHERE D.c_id = 'some id example: 107';
```

Query above won't work sicne SQL allow only records from one table to be removed with `INNER JOIN` so i will have to use two separate `DELETE` statements like this:

```
DELETE
FROM City 
WHERE c_id = '107'

DELETE 
FROM Buildings 
WHERE b_city = 'city that is tied to unique id 107'
```

My question is, what is the best practice to remove records that are tied in two tables? Since I have to use two separate SQL statements, should I pass City and then delete record(s) from Buildings table? or Should I create another query that will pull City from City table based on unique id and then remove record(s) from Buildings? If anyone knows better way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish your goal would be to set up your foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE. That way, whenever a row in the parent table is deleted, any related rows in the child table will be deleted automatically.

Here is an example of a way to alter a table in order to create a foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE:

```
ALTER TABLE child_table
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name
    FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

In your case, the child table would be Buildings and the parent table would be City. It sounds like you would have just city_number for the column. You'll have to fill in the name of your foreign key.

Comment: Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any example on how to do this Microsoft management studio?

Comment: @espresso_coffee : The code in Shannon's answer _is_ how you do this in Management Studio. If you already have an existing foreign key constraint that doesn't have the `on delete cascade` behavior, then I believe you will have to drop it and re-add it using a command like the one shown here.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10166420/shannon-fallon) mentioned, you can use ON DELETE CASCADE to delete data from parent and child tables.

Here is a working example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f5860/10

Answer (score 0):

Without writing out the code, here's what I would do:

1. Select all the ids to be deleted for buildings belonging to a city
2. Delete all the buildings
3. Delete the city
4. Put it in a stored procedure

Re-usable, self-contained, and clear.

This is a violation of SRP however, let me know if you care about that and I'll post a SRP based SQL solution.

Comment: What about CASCADE delete/update? Is that also a good option or there is something why that should be avoided?

Comment: @espresso_coffee The cascade delete/update may surprise an unsuspecting developer in a future scenario, as well as putting business logic in the database is generally considered undesirable unless you have a really good reason for it.

Comment: Isn't this relationship very strong and obvious plus if they use delete through the interface they will be notified about consequences of deleting that record?

Comment: @espresso_coffee I wouldn't assume a building belongs to a city, there's plenty of countryside for starters, say your business doesn't cater to buildings in cities anymore, your pk/fk will have to break.  The stored proc will remain the same, the cascade will have to get blown away creating a refactor scenario.

Comment: So what is the purpose of `CASCADE` then? What they are designed for? This seems like exact scenario where they should be used and your are trying to prove that stored procedures are better option. I'm trying to find benefits of using the stored procedure over cascade but one example that you mentioned above I can't find any other reason why I shouldn't use them. In my case this would be helpful because if City change at any point of time I also can use update cascade instead of manually updating hat field.